# SQL Server : SELECT something as ' VARIABLE '

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I did `SELECT` something as ' VARIABLE ', like this

```
SELECT  
    SUM(CASE WHEN BA_Idx = 503 THEN BIL_Debit ELSE 0 END) AS 'SUM_DEBIT_503',
    SUM(CASE WHEN BA_Idx = 504 THEN BIL_Debit ELSE 0 END) AS 'SUM_DEBIT_504'
FROM    
    Bill
WHERE   
    (@MEM_Idx = 0 OR MEM_Idx = @MEM_Idx) AND
    (LEFT(BIL_YYMMDD,7) = @BILM_YYMM) AND           
    BIL_IsValid = 'True'

SELECT @BILFC_TotalLaborCost = SUM_DEBIT_503 + SUM_DEBIT_504
```

I want to approach the VARIABLE(**'SUM_DEBIT_503', 'SUM_DEBIT_504'**) for calculating `@BILFC_TotalLaborCost`.

How can I approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the variables in the query. This way they're around for later use if you need them.

```
DECLARE @SumDebit503 <SOMETYPE>
DECLARE @SumDebit504 <SOMETYPE>

SELECT @SumDebit503 = SUM(CASE WHEN BA_Idx = 503 THEN BIL_Debit ELSE 0 END),
       @SumDebit504 = SUM(CASE WHEN BA_Idx = 504 THEN BIL_Debit ELSE 0 END)
FROM Bill
WHERE
    (@MEM_Idx = 0 OR MEM_Idx = @MEM_Idx)
    AND (LEFT(BIL_YYMMDD, 7) = @BILM_YYMM)
    AND BIL_IsValid = 'True'

SELECT  @BILFC_TotalLaborCost = @SumDebit503 + @SumDebit504
```

Comment: OMG, I've forgot a moment 'DECLARE'...sorry, and thank u! :)

Comment: @heejeongim, please consider accepting this answer if you feel it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do the assignment in the `SELECT` itself:

```
SELECT @BILFC_TotalLaborCost =
    SUM(CASE WHEN BA_Idx = 503 THEN BIL_Debit ELSE 0 END) +
    SUM(CASE WHEN BA_Idx = 504 THEN BIL_Debit ELSE 0 END)
FROM Bill
WHERE
    (@MEM_Idx = 0 OR MEM_Idx = @MEM_Idx)
    AND (LEFT(BIL_YYMMDD, 7) = @BILM_YYMM)
    AND BIL_IsValid = 'True'
```

Comment: Thank u, but I have to use the VARIABLE later, For inserting them into TABLE. I can't approach the VARIABLE  that declared like as 'VARIABLE ', can I?

Comment: I think Josh's answer is what you want.

Comment: YEP! I've forgot a moment 'DECLARE'...sorry, and thank u! :)